# How to connect to mongodb authentication instance which is one member of replica shard cluster?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

Why the account create from mongos, can not be use at replica instance?
the log :

```
[conn165] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for wuyg on admin from client 127.0.0.1 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user wuyg@admin
```

the user wuyg has these roles:

```
"roles" : [ { "role" : "clusterAdmin", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" } ]
```

and I can use the wuyg account when I connect from mongos.

My mongodb cluster has 3 config instance, and 1 shard which is a 3 members  replica cluster.
version:3.2.8

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In mongoDB users are kept in admin.system.users collections.
You can list users using commands:

```
use admin
db.system.users.find()
```

Each **ReplicaSet** instance has it's own admin database with separate **system.users** collection.

**Mongos**(shardedCluster) use **admin** database which is kept on config servers.

If you want to connect to mongos and replicaSet using the same user you have to create this user on **replicaSet**s and **mongos** separately

BTW It's better to use simple replicaSet configuration if you have only one shard. You can convert it to shardedCluster when you need additional capacity https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/.

Comment: Thank you very much. ReplicaSet and Mongos use different account, so the users I create from mongos can not use at ReplicaSet instance,and now I can't shutdown the ReplicaSet instance...

Comment: The ReplicaSet's MongoDB Instance need account, so I can't "use admin;db.system.users.find()"

Comment: You can restart mongod instances with option enableLocalhostAuthBypass: true (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/). You will be able to connect from localhost without password if there is no admin account created on this replicaSet